# Remove myself as editor on another person's project

Tags: google-app-engine

Somebody else, who owns an App Engine project, added me as an editor. We are no longer in touch, and I still have the permission. Is there a way to *remove myself* from the list?

Comment: App Engine is a tool used primarily for programming?? It's not a video game.

Comment: Your question is not related to programming or development.

Comment: In my view, this question is clearly related to programming and development.  It also directly involves tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: I think the better site for the question would be [Web Apps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). While it's true that App Engine is used primarily by programmers, the core issue here is about using a web app and has very little to do with programming.

Comment: @Yannis: It is on-topic for SO, as it can be for others. No need to close IMHO.

Comment: I've raised this for discussion on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274364/1253428) if anyone wants to debate the finer points.

Comment: @Yannis The fact that a question may be better on another SE site doesn't make it off-topic on SO. It never has.

Comment: @Bruno Where did I say that the question is off topic just because there might be a better site for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just checked on an app to which I was added as a developer.  It looks like you can, so long as:

1. You still have a login to the App Engine project
2. You are not the Project Owner

If you go to either the [old App Engine console](https://appengine.google.com/) or the new [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) you can remove yourself, so long as you are not the Owner.  Just click on *Permissions* in the left-hand menu and you should see the project team members.

On the old console, there should be a *Remove* button alongside your email.  On the new console, you should see a checkbox alongside your email address.

I would be interested to know if this works.

Comment: Yay! It works in the old console, but not the new one. There's no controls in the new console.